# using cron.php in magento without using crond

Tags: cron, schedule

I have to use [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/17515/s/cpc-strategy-feed-exporter-9392/?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRonuaTMZKXonjHpfsX57e0kXaS%2FlMI%2F0ER3fOvrPUfGjI4EScF0aPyQAgobGp5I5FEISrbYW7d3t60FUg%3D%3D) extension and I haven't access to cron jobs in my hosting.

I read that is possible to use cron.php also without access to cron jobs, how can I do this task?

Comment: which magento version are using

Comment: You can manually fire the cron by running http://yourstoredomain.com/cron.php

Comment: Ah, lazyhosting... Have a remote workstation with a scheduled curl or wget job that calls cron.php every 15 minutes. Don't shut off that workstation and make sure it has internet access 24/7. You don't need cron to function because of **that extension**. You need cron to function so Magento functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a cronjob in another hosting account to access the magento cron.php file, something like this

```
10 * * * * wget -O - http://magento-site.com/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

check this link for more info Using [CRON jobs to visit url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259530/using-cron-jobs-to-visit-url)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

create a file mycron.php on magento dir 
 and   add below code in this file

```
<?php
// Change current directory to the directory of current script
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));

require 'app/Mage.php';

if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
    exit;
}

// Only for urls
// Don't remove this
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);

umask(0);


try {

    Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
    Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');
        Mage::dispatchEvent('always');
        Mage::dispatchEvent('default');

} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
    exit(1);
}
```

**hint this file on browser..**

Comment: thanks for the reply! I try your solution but it doesn't work... have I change SCRIPT_NAME and SCRIPT_FILENAME ?